# Clustered annotations overwrite unclustered annotations

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview, mapkit

I have about 500 annotations on my MKMapView and I clustered them with [OCMapView](https://github.com/yinkou/OCMapView) wich replace the normal MKMapView. Anyway my annotation are clustered but not very well that why I need a little bit help. I see the clustered annotations and they update each other pretty good. If i zoom near to them they uncluster. So far so good but all the single annotations are named Cluster and their count is zero. Maybe it is only a minor/logical problem. For some understanding here some Code for you:

```
#pragma mark - map delegate
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView;

    // if it's a cluster
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[OCAnnotation class]])
    {

        OCAnnotation *clusterAnnotation = (OCAnnotation *)annotation;

        annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[aMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"ClusterView"];
        if (!annotationView)
        {
            annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"ClusterView"];
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
            annotationView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, -20);
        }
        //calculate cluster region
        CLLocationDistance clusterRadius = mapView.region.span.longitudeDelta * mapView.clusterSize * 111000 / 2.0f; //static circle size of cluster

        MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:clusterAnnotation.coordinate radius:clusterRadius * cos([annotation coordinate].latitude * M_PI / 180.0)];
        [circle setTitle:@"background"];
        [mapView addOverlay:circle];

        MKCircle *circleLine = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:clusterAnnotation.coordinate radius:clusterRadius * cos([annotation coordinate].latitude * M_PI / 180.0)];
        [circleLine setTitle:@"line"];
        [mapView addOverlay:circleLine];
        NSLog(@"%@", annotationArray);

        // set title
        clusterAnnotation.title = @"Cluster";
        clusterAnnotation.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Containing annotations: %d", [clusterAnnotation.annotationsInCluster count]];

        // set its image
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Pin.png"];

        // change pin image for group
        if (mapView.clusterByGroupTag)
        {
            if ([clusterAnnotation.groupTag isEqualToString:kTYPE1])
            {
                annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bananas.png"]; //OC examples for debug
            }
            else if([clusterAnnotation.groupTag isEqualToString:kTYPE2])
            {
                annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oranges.png"]; //OC examples for debug
            }
            clusterAnnotation.title = clusterAnnotation.groupTag;
        }
    }
    // If it's a single annotation
    else if([annotation isKindOfClass:[OCMapViewHelpAnnotation class]])
    {
        OCMapViewHelpAnnotation *singleAnnotation = (OCMapViewHelpAnnotation *)annotation;
        annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[aMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"singleAnnotationView"];
        if (!annotationView)
        {
            annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:singleAnnotation reuseIdentifier:@"singleAnnotationView"];
            annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
            annotationView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, -20);
        }
        singleAnnotation.title = singleAnnotation.groupTag;

        if ([singleAnnotation.groupTag isEqualToString:kTYPE1])
        {
            annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"banana.png"];
        }
        else if([singleAnnotation.groupTag isEqualToString:kTYPE2])
        {
            annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"orange.png"];
        }
    }
    // Error
    else
    {
        annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[aMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"errorAnnotationView"];
        if (!annotationView)
        {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"errorAnnotationView"];
            annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
            ((MKPinAnnotationView *)annotationView).pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        }
    }

    return annotationView;
}

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKCircle *circle = overlay;
    MKCircleView *circleView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithCircle:overlay];

    if ([circle.title isEqualToString:@"background"])
    {
        circleView.fillColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        circleView.alpha = 0.25;
    }
    else if ([circle.title isEqualToString:@"helper"])
    {
        circleView.fillColor = [UIColor redColor];
        circleView.alpha = 0.25;
    }
    else
    {
        circleView.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        circleView.lineWidth = 0.5;
    }

    return circleView;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [mapView removeOverlays:mapView.overlays];
    [mapView doClustering];
}
```

I noticed that `if([annotation isKindOfClass:[OCMapViewHelpAnnotation class]])` is never called but it have to if there are some annotations outside of the cluster.

Thank you for your attention

**EDIT**

[image: Annotation]

Normally it is filled with Informations like "Name" and "Street" but after plotting it's overwrite all with "Cluster" and "containing annotations: 0"

**EDIT 2**

```
- (void)loadKml:(NSURL *)url
{
    // parse the kml

    Parser *parser = [[Parser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    parser.rowElementName = @"Placemark";
    parser.elementNames = @[@"name", @"Snippet", @"coordinates", @"description"];
    //parser.attributeNames = @[@"src"];
    [parser parse];

    // add annotations for each of the entries
    annotationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *locationDetails in parser.items)
    {
        OCAnnotation *annotation = [[OCAnnotation alloc] init];
        annotation.title = locationDetails[@"name"];
        annotation.subtitle = locationDetails[@"Snippet"];
        NSArray *coordinates = [locationDetails[@"coordinates"] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([coordinates[1] floatValue], [coordinates[0] floatValue]);
        annotation.groupTag = annotation.title;
        [annotationArray addObject:annotation];
//        NSLog(@"%@", annotation.title);
    }
    [self.mapView addAnnotations:annotationArray];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the developer of OCMapView. Can you please explain, how to reproduce your problem?
This sounds really unusual, since you have posted the sample code...

---

**Update:**
The bug hides in your `loadKml:` method where you create a `OCAnnotation`.
`OCAnnotation` is reserved by by `OCMapView` for clusters. You shouldn't use `OCAnnotation` or any subclass as own annotations.

Comment: i just added a picture to display it better. i tryed to keep the code simple and only implement my own annotations for coding around.

Comment: Ok, i understand what the problem is but not how to reproduce it. It would be interesting to see more code especially how you add the annotations.

Comment: I use a kml-file wich store my locations with a bunch of information.

Comment: it seems to work i got a other problem with my `NSMutableArray` but this is something else.

Comment: it don't work... I always get `OCMapViewHelpAnnotation setCoordinate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` error. It's called `NSInvalidArgumentException`

Comment: Yeah that's because the `OCMapViewHelpAnnotation` doesn't have a setter for `coordinate`... Use the `initWithCoordinate` or implement it on your own.

Comment: do I need to call doClustering method after I run my for loop for adding annotations to the map ?